# How to terminate npm install

Tags: macos, terminal, node.js

I am running `npm install` usually I am pressing `ctrl+c` on Windows and it is cancelling the process. But it is not working for me on Mac.

I pressed `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+z` and tried different similar combinations `command|option + c|z` but nothing woking. Any ideas why?